# What action group should I use for my Idea/IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to develop a IntelliJ/Idea plugin that allows the following: When I Ctrl+click on a literal `int`, say `1234`, I want to navigate to the method `method_1234` if that exists in the current class.

What IntelliJ-"action group" do I add my new action into? From the tutorial for the plugin SDK I watched it seems that it is semantically important in which group I add my new action? Or am I wrong? Is only the code in the plugin important and the group is only where in the menus (or elsewhere) my new action appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Action group is semantically unimportant, it only determines in which menu your action will be visible to the user. For Ctrl+Click action, it seems to make no sense to show it in menu at all, so you can create an action without any group.